# How to combine multiple TDMS files in Python to a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, glob

I can open TDMS files on python individually, using the below code. But I am experiencing issues opening multiple files and combining them.

I have 31 files, of which I am only trying to combine the "cDAQ9184-1B49A20Mod2/ai3" data of each but keeping them in separate columns.

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile
import pandas as pd

# load file
tdms_file = TdmsFile("filepath.tdms")
# show groups
groups_data = tdms_file.groups()
print(groups_data)
# show channels
channels_data = tdms_file['reader_task'].channels()
print(channels_data)
# show data in channel
selected_data = tdms_file['reader_task']['cDAQ9184-1B49A20Mod2/ai3']
print(selected_data.data)

# load into df
df = pd.DataFrame(data=selected_data.data)
```

I have used the glob function before to combine multiple csv files into one dataframe but I am unsure whether I code reuse this code and change it for TDMS as it uses data channels rather than columns?
This is the code I used to loop csv files:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import itertools

# glob to get all csv files
path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join('filepath/', "*.csv"))

df = []

# loop list of csv files
for idx, f in enumerate(csv_files, 1):
    # only keep AE (4th column, index 3)
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, usecols=[3], skiprows=[0])
    colname = f"{idx}"
    temp_df.rename(columns={3: colname}, inplace=True)
    df.append(temp_df)

df_final = pd.concat(df, axis="columns")
```

Any help or insight into how I could have all the TDMS files into 1 dataframe would be greatly appreciated!